# Edit object method doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A page displays a list of articles where in each article there is an **Edit** button.
The problem is that when I click **Edit** I get the following message:

`Couldn't find Article with 'id'=#<Article::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xsomeHEX>`

My `.html.erb` file looks something like this:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= article.title %>
  <%= article.body %>
  <% link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@articles) %>
<% end %>
```

I made the following controller with the following methods.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  include ArticlesHelper

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @articles = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update(article_params)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `edit_article_path` is wrong, you're passing the entire relation into it.

```
<% link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(article) %>
```